# Generating an array in the view and passing it into the controller

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

It's a little strange but I cannot think of a better way to get it done.

First of all this is my code:

The router to get the view in the first place

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Account.findOne(
    {
      _id: req.user._id,
    },
    function(err, acc) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      // console.log(acc.websites);
      res.render('reports/index', {
        title: 'Reports!',
        websites: acc.websites,
        user: req.user,
      });
    }
  );
});
```

The view:

```
<% include ./../partials/header.ejs %>
  <h1 class="text-center">This is your report page</h1>
  <form method="post">
    <% for(let i=0; i<websites.length; i++){ let website = websites[i]; %>
      <fieldset>
        <label for="website<%=i%>" class="col-sm-2">Website <%=i+1%></label>
        <input name="website<%=i%>" id="website<%=i%>" value="<%=website%>" type="text" />
      </fieldset>
      <% } %>
        <a href="/report/<%=  %>" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-offset-2">Generate report</a>
  </form>
  <% include ./../partials/footer.ejs %>
```

The router, that's supposed to fire up after the on click.

```
router.get('/reports', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.user.isPremium == false) {
    // Free user - Single report
    var builtWithCall = `https://api.builtwith.com/free1/api.json?KEY=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&LOOKUP=${website}`;
    let website = req.body.website0;
    console.log(website);
  }
});
```

How it works: The controller finds the account, grabs an array from inside of it, sends it to the view. The view prints it out and allows to make some changes to the values.

And now is where the problems begin. I need to gather the new values into an array and send it to the next router, which will then use them to call a bunch of APIs and print out the data. How do I gather the array and pass it to the controller? Also, should I use GET or POST?

Comment: The button should not be an anchor unless you want the click to cause a page redirect.

Comment: I need to send it and redirect to another view. I don't know how to send it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your logic, the `name` attribute will have the following form: `name=website[0...n]`. With that in mind, we can filter out the keys to gather all the `website[n]` into an array you seek:

```js
const example = {
    website0: 'example',
    website1: 'example',
    website2: 'example',
    website3: 'example',
    shouldBeIgnored: 'ignoreMe',
    ignore: 'shouldIgnore'
}

const websites = Object.keys(example).filter(key => key.startsWith('website'))
console.log(websites)
```

So you're controller can be:

```
router.get('/reports', (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.user.isPremium) {
    // Free user - Single report
    const builtWithCall = `https://api.builtwith.com/free1/api.json?KEY=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000&LOOKUP=${website}`;
    const websites = Object.keys(req.body).filter(key => key.startsWith('website'));
    console.log(websites);
  }
});
```

Comment: Wait so how do I send it? Do I send it with an anchor or just a POST?

Comment: You send it with the view as you did before: `res.render('my-view', { websites })`

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding. The websites will change in the view. And from this view I need to send them to another controller. How would I represent it in the code? Just POST it normally and then filter them out in the controller?